# C++ Bind Return Type Template Arguments

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, c++14

I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
class TD;   // For displaying type

void f(int, int, int) {  }

int main() {
    auto g = std::bind(f, std::placeholders::_1, 2, 2);
    TD<decltype(g)> td1;
    return 0;
}
```

In this code `TD` is a template trick for showing its template argument passed via `decltype`.

Output of the compiler follows (compiled in `C++14` mode):

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:10:18: error: aggregate 'TD<std::_Bind<void (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, int, int))(int, int, int)> > td1' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
  TD<decltype(g)> td1;
                  ^
```

Well, incomplete type error is of course excepted. But what makes me curious in this error message is `std::_Bind<void (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, int, int))(int, int, int)>`. I can comprehend that `std::_Bind` is a proxy class which defines `operator()` and makes our purpose possible. But its template argument `void (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, int, int))(int, int, int)` made me woow! How should I interpret it? Does it have any usefulness in user-land code? How can I create my own classes making use of this declaration?

Answer (score 3):

```
void (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, int, int))(int, int, int)
```

This declares an unnamed function taking three parameters (`std::_Placeholder<1>`, `int` and `int`) and returning a pointer to a function that takes three `int`s and returns `void`.

Let's simplify a little. First consider a simple function declaration:

```
void f(int)
```

Now, in parameter declarations (of functions or templates) you can omit the name and you get

```
void (int)
```

which, if used in a parameter list of a function declaration, would be equivalent to a function pointer `void(*)(int)`.

A function that returns a function pointer is declared like this:

```
void (*f(int))(int);
//   ^       ^         <- this pair of parentheses changes
//                        the order in which the declaration is parsed.
//                        Without it, the return type would be `void*`
//                        and you'd get a syntax error
```

Now you can remove the name `f` and you basically get the same thing that you were asking about.

Its uses? Apparently it's useful when implementing `std::bind` :) I can't think of anything else right now...

Comment: Woow! How I forgot applying that simple type declaration reading! :) Now only one thing left. If you could elaborate how 'std::bind` makes use of it, that would be great! :)

Comment: @jnbrq-CanberkSönmez If you're thinking about using `_Placeholder`, know that it is non-standard. You would be using a type that is defined only in this specific version of the compiler. It isn't even guaranteed to work in future versions of the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 marked the advent of [`function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) which made defining function pointers far easier:

> Instances of std::function can store, copy, and invoke any Callable target -- functions, lambda expressions, bind expressions, or other function objects, as well as pointers to member functions and pointers to data members.

So for example let's say that you needed to take in a function pointer to `string foo(int param) { return to_string(param); }` in one of your functions. Pre-C++11, your function would need to look like:

```
void bar(string (*func)(int)) { cout << func(13) << endl; }
```

Let's go a step further and say you wanted to expand `foo` to: `string foo2(int lhs, int rhs) { return to_string(lhs + rhs); }`. But now you want to cram that back into `bar`. Doing this `bar(bind(&foo2, placeholders::_1, 42));` would give you an error like this:

> cannot convert 'std::_Bind_helper (*)(int, int), const std::_Placeholder<1>&, int>::type {aka std::_Bind (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, int))(int, int)>}' to 'std::string (*)(int) {aka std::basic_string (*)(int)}' for argument '1' to 'void bar(std::string (*)(int))'

You could get around this error by creating a function that took an implementation specific argument, like: `void bar2(_Bind<string (*(_Placeholder<1>, int))(int, int)> func) { cout << func(13) << endl; }` which could successfully be called with: `bar2(bind(&foo2, placeholders::_1, 42));`. The reason that this is implementation specific is that the types: `_Bind` and `_Placeholder` are non-standard. In fact the return of [`bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) is:

> A function object of unspecified type T

Which brings us to `function`. If you weren't already turned off by the syntax the limitations of a function pointer, you'll need to take a `function` parameter to accept an object created by `bind`. Let's make a new `bar` using `function`:

```
void bar3(function<string(int)> func) { cout << func(13) << endl; }
```

This is capable of accepting both the traditional function pointer and the `bind` functor. Additionally it can handle lambdas, so you can do this: `bar3([](int param) { return to_string(param); });`

I've created a [live example](http://ideone.com/VRuNAr) so you can play around with this some hopefully the benefits of the `function` object are clear.

Comment: Well, actually not exactly what I need to know. My question is mainly `void (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, int, int))(int, int, int)` means and where it can be used.

Comment: @jnbrq-CanberkSönmez Actually, this did address how to use the return of `bind` it just wasn't specific about why you should use `function<void(int, int)>` instead of `_Bind<void (*(_Placeholder<1>, int, int))(int, int, int)>` I've edited the answer to explain that. tldr: The type returned by `bind` is implementation specific. You must use a `function` object to accept it.

Comment: Unless you actually need type erasure, it's better by far to use a function template and accept the function object as is.

Comment: @T.C. I feel like you're giving me a valuable piece of information here, but I don't understand it. Can you clarify what you are saying the better way to do this is?

Comment: `template<class F> void bar4(F func) { cout << func(13) << endl; }`, or even `template<class F> void bar4(F&& func) { cout << std::forward<F>(func)(13) << endl; }`

Comment: @T.C. I got it now. Yeah, I thought about writing the function as a template to support closure types, but since the question was specifically about types I felt it was helpful to actually specify the exact type being used. What do you think? I could append the answer to improve correctness, but as it is I think the answer is so long no one's taken the time to read it all the way through. :S